# Passing Dynamic Headers to loki Ingress

Tags: header, kubernetes-ingress, nginx-ingress, grafana-loki

We have the below nginx .conf settings in our local vm and it is working fine.
Summary: We are sending logs to loki by having nginx in front of loki where we have two levels of authentication:

1. Writing the logs
2. Reading the logs

The below file is working fine, now we want to move this nginx to k8.

In k8 what we want is to use our LB (projectname.dev.url.com) to write the logs under the path **/loki/api/v1/push** and read the logs under the path **/logs. **

Where we are right now is, we are able to successfully do a curl command towards our read path.
which is **/projectname.dev.url.com/logs**, however we are not able to push logs to loki write path(projectname.dev.url.com/loki/api/v1/push) as it is expecting headers.
Our ingress config file looks like below : can some one please help me in passing headers in k8 ingress  set up, similar to how we pass in our VM nginx set up

```
upstream "FQDN Hostname2" {
# server XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 weight=1;
  server XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 weight=1;
  server XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 weight=1;
  server XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 weight=1;
  server XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX:443 weight=1;
}
map $remote_user $loki_scope_org_id {
  "~^(?<scope_org_id>[^#]*)"  $scope_org_id;
}

server {
    listen 443 ssl;
    server_name FQDN HOstname;
    ssl_certificate /etc/pki/tls/certs/FQDN HOstname.crt;
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/pki/tls/private/FQDN HOstname.key;
    ssl_protocols TLSv1.2 TLSv1.3;
    client_max_body_size 2G;
    client_body_buffer_size 50M;
    location /loki/api/v1/push {
        log_subrequest on;
        mirror /loki/api/v2/push;
        auth_basic "Please provide X-Scope-OrgID";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_agents;-----------**Writing Credentials**
        proxy_pass http://FQDN HOstname:3100/loki/api/v1/push;
        proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $loki_scope_org_id;



    }
    location /loki/api/v2/push {
        internal;
        log_subrequest on;
        auth_basic "Please provide X-Scope-OrgID";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_agents;
        proxy_pass https://FQDN Hostname2/logs/loki/api/v1/push;
        proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $loki_scope_org_id;



    }
    location / {
        auth_basic "Please provide X-Scope-OrgID";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_grafana;
        proxy_pass http://FQDN HOstname:3100/;
        proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $remote_user;



    }
    location /logs {
        auth_basic "Please provide X-Scope-OrgID";
        auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/.htpasswd_grafana;
        proxy_pass https://FQDN Hostname2/logs;
        proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $remote_user;



    }


    access_log  /var/lib/loki/nginx/LOGNAME_access.log  main;
    error_log /var/lib/loki/nginx/LOGNAME_error.log warn;

}
```

-------------Ingress config file-------------

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: Ingress
metadata:
  annotations:
    meta.helm.sh/release-name: loki
    meta.helm.sh/release-namespace: loki
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-realm: Authentication Required
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-secret: **basic-auth**
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/auth-type: basic
    nginx.ingress.kubernetes.io/rewrite-target: /$2

  creationTimestamp: "2022-10-26T20:34:42Z"
  generation: 9
  labels:
    app.kubernetes.io/component: gateway
    app.kubernetes.io/instance: loki
    app.kubernetes.io/managed-by: Helm
    app.kubernetes.io/name: loki-distributed
    app.kubernetes.io/version: 2.4.2
    helm.sh/chart: loki-distributed-0.47.4
  name: loki-loki-distributed-gateway
  namespace: loki
  resourceVersion: "94038120"
  uid: a9175373-458b-41ff-a261-d984e266a54e
spec:
  ingressClassName: nginx
  rules:
  - http:
      paths:
      - backend:
          service:
            name: loki-loki-distributed-gateway
            port:
              number: 443
        path: /logs(/|$)(.*)
        pathType: Prefix
      - backend:
          service:
             name: loki-loki-distributed-distributor
             port:
               number: 443
        path: /logs/loki/api/v1/push
        pathType: Exact
  tls:
  - hosts:
    - '*.fqdn.fqdn.net'
status:
  loadBalancer:
    ingress:
    - ip: X.X.X.159
    - ip: X.X.X.17
    - ip: X.X.X.49
    - ip: X.X.X.72
    - ip: X.X.X.76
    - ip: X.X.X.78
    - ip: X.X.X.83
    - ip: X.X.X.120
    - ip: X.X.X.123
    - ip: X.X.X.127
    - ip: X.X.X.144
    - ip: X.X.X.145
    - ip: X.X.X.167
    - ip: X.X.X.168
    - ip: X.X.X.171
    - ip: X.X.X.177
    - ip: X.X.X.178
    - ip: X.X.X.183
    - ip: X.X.X.185
    - ip: X.X.X.186
    - ip: X.X.X.190
    - ip: X.X.X.197
    - ip: X.X.X.4
    - ip: X.X.X.6
```

I tried creating configmap file in ingress - which is shown as below, i have added "map" field in ingress configmap , similar to what we have in our vm set up,my question is  **how would **$remote_user** be mapped to username which is present in our secret file** - **basic-auth**.
I have added auth file to ingress file . please see my main post.
Any help would be very appreciated.

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  /dev/stderr;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}


http {
  client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
  proxy_temp_path       /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
  fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
  uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
  scgi_temp_path        /tmp/scgi_temp;
  **map $remote_user $loki_scope_org_id {
    "~^(?<scope_org_id>[^#]*)"  $scope_org_id;
  }**

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   /dev/stderr  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  resolver rke2-coredns-rke2-coredns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;

  server {
    listen             8080;

    location = / {
      return 200 'OK';
      auth_basic off;
    }

    location = /api/prom/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
    }

    location = /api/prom/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /api/prom/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
      proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $loki_scope_org_id;
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /loki/api/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }
  }
}
```

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  /dev/stderr;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}


http {
  client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
  proxy_temp_path       /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
  fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
  uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
  scgi_temp_path        /tmp/scgi_temp;
  map $remote_user $loki_scope_org_id {
    "~^(?<scope_org_id>[^#]*)"  $scope_org_id;
  }

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   /dev/stderr  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  resolver rke2-coredns-rke2-coredns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;

  server {
    listen             8080;

    location = / {
      return 200 'OK';
      auth_basic off;
    }

    location = /api/prom/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
    }

    location = /api/prom/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /api/prom/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
      proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $loki_scope_org_id;
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /loki/api/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }
  }
}
```

```
worker_processes  5;  ## Default: 1
error_log  /dev/stderr;
pid        /tmp/nginx.pid;
worker_rlimit_nofile 8192;

events {
  worker_connections  4096;  ## Default: 1024
}


http {
  client_body_temp_path /tmp/client_temp;
  proxy_temp_path       /tmp/proxy_temp_path;
  fastcgi_temp_path     /tmp/fastcgi_temp;
  uwsgi_temp_path       /tmp/uwsgi_temp;
  scgi_temp_path        /tmp/scgi_temp;
  **map $remote_user $loki_scope_org_id {
    "~^(?<scope_org_id>[^#]*)"  $scope_org_id;
  }**

  default_type application/octet-stream;
  log_format   main '$remote_addr - $remote_user [$time_local]  $status '
        '"$request" $body_bytes_sent "$http_referer" '
        '"$http_user_agent" "$http_x_forwarded_for"';
  access_log   /dev/stderr  main;
  sendfile     on;
  tcp_nopush   on;
  resolver rke2-coredns-rke2-coredns.kube-system.svc.cluster.local;

  server {
    listen             8080;

    location = / {
      return 200 'OK';
      auth_basic off;
    }

    location = /api/prom/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
    }

    location = /api/prom/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /api/prom/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/push {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-distributor.loki.svc.cluster.local:310
      proxy_set_header X-Scope-OrgID $loki_scope_org_id;
    }

    location = /loki/api/v1/tail {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-querier.loki.svc.cluster.local:3100$re
      proxy_set_header Upgrade $http_upgrade;
      proxy_set_header Connection "upgrade";
    }

    location ~ /loki/api/.* {
      proxy_pass       http://loki-loki-distributed-query-frontend.loki.svc.cluster.local:
    }
  }
}
```